# FlyCapture SDK problems on Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, sdk, flycapture

I am having problems with the flycapture SDK (FlyCapture v2.6 Rel 2) on Visual Studio. This is used for BlackFly camera.

I am getting the following errors:

```
Error   1   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::Error(void)" (__imp_??0Error@FlyCapture2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   2   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::Error(class FlyCapture2::Error const &)" (__imp_??0Error@FlyCapture2@@QAE@ABV01@@Z) referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   3   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::~Error(void)" (__imp_??1Error@FlyCapture2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl PrintError(class FlyCapture2::Error)" (?PrintError@@YAXVError@FlyCapture2@@@Z)  C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   4   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual void __thiscall FlyCapture2::Error::PrintErrorTrace(void)const " (__imp_?PrintErrorTrace@Error@FlyCapture2@@UBEXXZ) referenced in function "void __cdecl PrintError(class FlyCapture2::Error)" (?PrintError@@YAXVError@FlyCapture2@@@Z)    C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   5   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::BusManager(void)" (__imp_??0BusManager@FlyCapture2@@QAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain  C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   6   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::~BusManager(void)" (__imp_??1BusManager@FlyCapture2@@UAE@XZ) referenced in function _wmain C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   7   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::GetNumOfCameras(unsigned int *)" (__imp_?GetNumOfCameras@BusManager@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@PAI@Z) referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   8   error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "__declspec(dllimport) public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::BusManager::GetCameraFromIndex(unsigned int,class FlyCapture2::PGRGuid *)" (__imp_?GetCameraFromIndex@BusManager@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@IPAVPGRGuid@2@@Z) referenced in function _wmain   C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   66  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Camera::ValidateFormat7Settings(struct FlyCapture2::Format7ImageSettings const *,bool *,struct FlyCapture2::Format7PacketInfo *)" (?ValidateFormat7Settings@Camera@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@PBUFormat7ImageSettings@2@PA_NPAUFormat7PacketInfo@2@@Z)  C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   67  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Camera::WaitForBufferEvent(class FlyCapture2::Image *,unsigned int)" (?WaitForBufferEvent@Camera@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@PAVImage@2@I@Z) C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   68  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Camera::WriteRegister(unsigned int,unsigned int,bool)" (?WriteRegister@Camera@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@II_N@Z)    C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   69  error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol "public: virtual class FlyCapture2::Error __thiscall FlyCapture2::Camera::WriteRegisterBlock(unsigned short,unsigned int,unsigned int const *,unsigned int)" (?WriteRegisterBlock@Camera@FlyCapture2@@UAE?AVError@2@GIPBII@Z) C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.obj BlackFlyMultiTrigger
Error   70  error LNK1120: 69 unresolved externals  C:\Users\dahl2\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\BlackFlyMultiTrigger\Debug\BlackFlyMultiTrigger.exe    BlackFlyMultiTrigger
```

and to my understanding the problem lies in the directories (include and library).

I have downloaded the FlyCapture SDK v2.6 Release 2 for Windows 32-bit and 64-bit.

In my project I have added the following properties:

**Configuration Properties -> Linker -> Additional Library Directories : C:\Program Files\Point Grey Research\FlyCapture2\lib64\FlyCapture2_v100.lib**

**Configuration Properties -> C/C++ -> Additional Include Directories : C:\Program Files\Point Grey Research\FlyCapture2\include**

I have tried to do this with the 32-bit and 64-bit SDK and with different lib's. But I don't know where I have done something wrong. All help is appreciated!!!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have been working on finding the problem, and now I have. The FlyCapture2 SDK is not supported by VS2012 by default. I had to make some changes.

1. First I added the properties (as written above), but using the 32-bit SDK.
2. Then I entered the folder where SDK was installed. Here I went to src\vsprops\VS10 and made a copy of the FlyCapture2.props file.
3. Then I renamed the copy, for example "FlyCapture2Changed.props"
4. Open the "FlyCapture2Changed.props" (notepad, text editor, etc) and found the line:

NB! there should not be space between < and AdditionalDependencies (same for < / ), had some trouble with the editor here (text went missing).

< AdditionalDependencies>FlyCapture2_$(PlatformToolset).lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)< /AdditionalDependencies>

and changed it to:

< AdditionalDependencies>FlyCapture2_v100.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)< /AdditionalDependencies>

After this was done I had to do some changes to the project. Under your project you should go to property manager and rightclick on Debug | Win32 and select "Add Existing Property Sheet" and select the "FlyCapture2Changed.props" I have made.

After this was done it worked!

Comment: Wow, thank you so much! I've been searching for two days now and this finally solved my issue.